# Are all maven mirrors the same?

Tags: maven, maven-3, janusgraph

I have following error when using `mvn clean install` to build janusgraph examples

```
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for 
org.janusgraph:janusgraph-examples:[unknown-version]: 
Could not find artifact org.janusgraph:janusgraph:pom:0.4.0 in alimaven
 (http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) 
and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM 
@ line 3, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

According to the error, I opened my `setting.xml` of maven, The mirror conf is

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>alimaven</id>
      <name>aliyun maven</name>
      <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
<mirrors>
```

It says it could not find in this mirror, so would it work if I change another mirror? Are all the mirrors the same (except for the network speed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is a large number of different Maven repositories with different content. Usually, though, you draw most of your content from MavenCentral:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/